# Drop down menu for wordpress theme not working

Tags: wordpress

Here is my website http://www.ntchrist.com/  I am using the theme katla..I have added submenu under section but the dropdown is not working for that..please help me out from this.

Comment: I can't see any actual submenus in there http://prntscr.com/9ycxp8
It may be the theme custom function that handle that menu & causing problem. You can start to investigate from header.php & function.php files

Answer (score 0):

Place your sub-menu under the  menu called "section"  [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoTNw.png)
in this picture sub menus are placed under "लॉग इन". And you can see in the image that the sub-menus have label "sub item".